# Convert column data to row data separated by comma and group by column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wants to convert column to single row separated by comma.

Current Table :

```
main_cat | sub_cat |
--------------------
main 1   | sub 1   |
main 1   | sub 2   |
main 2   | sub 2   |
main 2   | sub 3   |
main 3   | sub 1   |
```

Expected Table

```
group_main             | main 1       | main 2     | main 3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
main 1, main 2, main 3 | sub 1, sub 2 |sub 2, sub 3|sub 1   |
```

I tried `GROUP_CONCAT` but not getting exact output

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select group_concat(distinct main_cat order by main_cat) as group_main,
       group_concat(case when main_cat = 'main 1' then sub_cat end order by sub_cat) as main_1,
       group_concat(case when main_cat = 'main 2' then sub_cat end order by sub_cat) as main_2,
       group_concat(case when main_cat = 'main 3' then sub_cat end order by sub_cat) as main_3
from t;
```